# Pythonic wrapper for Redis with serialization

Tags: python, serialization, redis, wrapper

I've tried [redish](https://github.com/ask/redish).
It looks pretty good, but it seems to be dead, and there are no auth option (improved in some forks). I took a look at [redis-natives](https://github.com/peta/redis-natives-py) and [redis_wrap](https://github.com/amix/redis_wrap), but it seems that there's no serialization.

I'm not proud of my "not invented here" syndrom in the past, so i'm looking for some nice wrapper if it exists. :)

UDP: The simplest own bicycle in django, IMHO, looks like:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
import redis
import anyjson

r = redis.Redis(password=setting('REDIS_PASSWORD'))

class ToRedisMixIn(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ToRedisMixIn, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        exclude = ['id']
        redis_exclude = getattr(self, 'redis_exclude', None)
        redis_key_name = getattr(self, 'redis_key_name', None) or '%ss' % self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        if redis_exclude:
            exclude += redis_exclude
        model_dict = model_to_dict(self, exclude=exclude)
        r.hset(redis_key_name, self.id, anyjson.serialize(model_dict))
```

Usage:

```
class Device(ToRedisMixIn, models.Model):
    host            = models.IPAddressField()
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    redis_exclude = ['description']
    redis_key_name = 'devices'
```

Not best, but works.

Comment: Did you try this wrapper? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Comment: Yes, it was first wrapper i've used. And i use it right now, but i have a lot of serial/deserial issues. I've made some wrapper for data serialization (json) in hashes, but thought: what if it's already done by someone..

Comment: How about just flattening a multi dimensional dict into a straight key -> val dict, where the keys are namespaced? That's what I've decided to do prior to storing in redis, then there's no conversion issue.